Any docker image for Nvidia Jetson AGX Orin
I wrote a devcontainer.json and a dockerfile in x86 environment like this.
{
    "name": "CUDA",
    "image": "nvidia/cuda:12.4.1-cudnn-devel-ubuntu22.04",
    "runArgs": [
        "--gpus=all"
    ],
    "remoteEnv": {
        "PATH": "${containerEnv:PATH}:/usr/local/cuda/bin",
        "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64",
        "XLA_FLAGS": "--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=/usr/local/cuda"
    },
    "postCreateCommand": [
        "nvidia-smi"
    ],
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
                "mhutchie.git-graph",
                "ms-vscode.cpptools"
            ]
        }
    },
    "build": {
        // Sets the run context to one level up instead of the .devcontainer folder.
        "context": "..",
        "dockerfile": "../Dockerfile"
    }
}

Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Install CUDA Toolkit 12.4
RUN wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.4.1/local_installers/cuda_12.4.1_550.54.15_linux.run \
  && chmod +x cuda_12.4.1_550.54.15_linux.run \
  && ./cuda_12.4.1_550.54.15_linux.run --toolkit --silent --toolkitpath=/usr/local/cuda-12.4 \
  && rm cuda_12.4.1_550.54.15_linux.run

Everything is well but when I tried to build the docker image in Jetson AGX Orin, I saw these error messages:

Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create
failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process


cuda-compat-12-4 : PreDepends: nvidia-l4t-core but it is not
installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
packages.

I think maybe I can find some pre-build docker images for Jetson AGX Orin, then I can install my packages inside.
I also tried this docker image:

https://hub.docker.com/r/balenalib/jetson-agx-orin-devkit

But after I install CUDA toolkit I still see the error, and still can not run nvidia-smi cmd.

cuda-compat-12-4 : PreDepends: nvidia-l4t-core but it is not
installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
packages.

